# Unknown function 'translate3d'

Tags: css, sass

Sass gives me an error: Unknown function 'translate3d', highly confused on why sass doesn't recognise it.

Code, if it can be of any use:

```
.app-cursor {
z-index: 1000;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
border: 1px solid black;
pointer-events: none;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
```

Comment: can you share more codes?

Comment: It's a custom cursor component made in reactjs, so this is the only scss code i have for it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem with sass itself, rather than a problem with your IDE (Webstorm, I suppose). It should be already fixed by now in version 2021.3.2
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-54134